# skip header of csv while reading multiple files into rdd in scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, header, rdd

I am trying to read multiple csvs into an rdd from a path. This path has many csvs Is there a way I can avoid the headers while reading all the csvs into rdd? or use spotsRDD to omit out the header without having to use filter or deal with each csv individually and then union them?

```
val path ="file:///home/work/csvs/*"
    val spotsRDD= sc.textFile(path)
    println(spotsRDD.count())
```

Thanks

Comment: which version of spark are u using?

Comment: @VladoDemcak :Unfortunately spark 1.0.0 .  We need to stick to rdds right now until we upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is pity you are using spark 1.0.0.

You can use [***CSV Data Source***](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) for Apache Spark **but** this library **requires** `Spark 1.3+` and btw. this library was inlined to `Spark 2.x`.

But we can analyse and implement something similar.

When we look into the [`com/databricks/spark/csv/DefaultSource.scala`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/1ae649285462df1af1411593e2abe589de2d704c/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/DefaultSource.scala#L87) there is

```
val useHeader = parameters.getOrElse("header", "false")
```

and then in the [com/databricks/spark/csv/CsvRelation.scala](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/CsvRelation.scala#L90) there is

```
// If header is set, make sure firstLine is materialized before sending to executors.
val filterLine = if (useHeader) firstLine else null

baseRDD().mapPartitions { iter =>
// When using header, any input line that equals firstLine is assumed to be header
val csvIter = if (useHeader) {
  iter.filter(_ != filterLine)
} else {
  iter
}
parseCSV(csvIter, csvFormat)
```

so if we assume the first line is only once in `RDD` (our csv rows) we can do something like in the example below:

CSV example file:

```
Latitude,Longitude,Name
48.1,0.25,"First point"
49.2,1.1,"Second point"
47.5,0.75,"Third point"
```

---

```
scala> val csvData = sc.textFile("test.csv")
csvData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = test.csv MapPartitionsRDD[24] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> val header = csvDataRdd.first
header: String = Latitude,Longitude,Name

scala> val csvDataWithoutHeaderRdd = csvDataRdd.mapPartitions{iter => iter.filter(_ != header)}
csvDataWithoutHeaderRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[25] at mapPartitions at <console>:28

scala> csvDataWithoutHeaderRdd.foreach(println)
49.2,1.1,"Second point"
48.1,0.25,"First point"
47.5,0.75,"Third point"
```

Comment: this won't work in case of multiple csv files read in a single rdd..??